# Set iframe source to instance of an object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a page called `Calendar.aspx` with an `iframe` in of it. Currently, when the page is loaded, it calls a JavaScript function which sets the `iframe`'s `src` attribute like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetCalendarIFrame()
{
    document.getElementById("CalendarFrame").src = "./CalendarIframe.aspx";
}
</script>

<iframe id="CalendarFrame">

<script type="text/javascript">
SetCalendarIFrame();
</script>
```

Several variables are set in `Calendar.aspx.cs` (`Calender.aspx`'s code-behind) on `Page_Load`, including an object of type `AuthenticatedUser`, which I'd like to pass to the `CalendarIframe` I'm instantiating to fill the `iframe`.

Is there a way, instead of just setting the `iframe`'s `src` to `CalendarIframe.aspx`, to instantiate a new object of type `CalendarIframe`and assigning it as the source of the `iframe`? I'm guessing the solution will involve instantiating a new `CalendarIframe` from within `Calendar.aspx.cs` and passing the `AuthenticatedUser` to `CalendarIframe`'s constructor, but I'm not sure how to then set the `iframe`'s `src` to this particular instance of `CalendarIframe`.

I'm fairly new to C# so my understanding of how the language works may be a bit flawed... Please let me know if you need any clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but the answer is probably no, there's no way to set an iFrames source to an instance of an object, it has to be a string ?

Comment: The iframe's src is just a url to another page that loads in the iframe. It's not really a object other than a String.

Comment: I ended up creating a few ASP `hiddenfield`s for the important fields of `AuthenticatedUser`. The code-behind sets the value of these `hiddenfield`s to the values of `AuthenticatedUser`'s fields. The iframe's `src` is then set to `CalendarIframe.aspx` with the `hiddenfield` values appended to the URL as URL parameters, which `CalendarIframe.aspx.cs` gets from the Request object. Not the most elegant solution but it gets the job done.

I could also have serialized the `AuthenticatedUser` object and passed it to the `src` attribute as a URL parameter, but this app needs to support old browsers.